# zeroinitializer in global integer array in bitcode

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to translate a global variable "int m[6];" to

```
@m = common global [6 x i32] zeroinitializer, align 16
```

For this, I have done the following. However, the following implementation generates the bitcode without "zeroinitializer". As a result of this, lli fails to run the generated bitcode.

```
   auto arrType = ArrayType::get(
            Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext),6);
   TheModule->getOrInsertGlobal("m",arrType);
   auto gvar = TheModule->getNamedGlobal("m");
   gvar->setLinkage(GlobalVariable::CommonLinkage);
   gvar->setAlignment(MaybeAlign(16));

@m = common global [6 x i32], align 16
```

My question is how to add "zeroinitializer" to the @m to make lli execute my generated bitcode.

Comment: You need to call `gvar->setInitializer()`; I seem to recall that there's a convenience function to make a zeroinitilizer given a `Type*` but I don't use it, I'm afraid. (I have a convenience function of my own.)

Answer (score 0):

**gvar->setInitializer()** works as *amt* suggests! The following is the implementation which produces "zeroinitializer" for my gvar.

```
auto arrType = ArrayType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext),6);
SmallVector<Constant*, 16> values;
for (auto i=0; i < iptr->i_numelem; i++)
    values.push_back(llvm::Constant::getIntegerValue(
        Builder.getInt32Ty(),APInt(32, 0)));
Constant *init = llvm::ConstantArray::get(arrType, values);
gvar->setInitializer(init);
```

However, I am getting the following build warning. I wonder how to get rid of this warning.

> warning: invalid conversion from 'llvm::Type*' to 'llvm::ArrayType*'
> [-fpermissive]   124 |     Constant *init =
> llvm::ConstantArray::get(iptr->u.ltype, values);
> |                                               ~~~~~~~~^~~~~
> |                                                       |
> |                                                       llvm::Type*

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I made a downcasting mistake. I realized that the first type of the get() is ArrayType *. The warning message is gone now.